# How to add 3rd party tools to Windows installation media to use live from CMD?

Tags: windows, media, installer

For example, while running Windows installation media, it's possible to summon CMD and use tools like diskpart, bdcedit, etc from `X:\Sources`.

The reason is a tool called gptgen, which converts an MBR partition table to GPT without data loss. And I need to run it live on installation.

And so I need to use that third party tool on installation, but I can't. I tried to copy the executable to /sources directory of an installation media, but it seems that windows builds a dynamic filesystem, and you can only use the content which is on default .dll's.

So how to add that program to the installation to be able to use it?

Comment: Why not just plug in a(nother) USB drive with your utility on it, and then run it from there?

Comment: You could also partition a drive and have the files there.